# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Tags: php, sql, arrays, fatal-error

cant fine the error,can some one help me?

```
$sql_project_material = "SELECT * FROM project_material";
if($result_project_material = $connect->query($sql_project_material))
{
    $rows_project_material = $result_project_material->fetch_array();
    $total_project_material = $result_project_material->num_rows;
    $num_project_material = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code ot the `$connect::query()` function? Most likely the function is not returning an object if the query result is empty?

Comment: <?php } while($rows_project_material = $rows_project_material->fetch_array()); } ?>

Comment: Are you using the `mysqli_connect` function to create your `$connect` object?

Comment: yes i use mysqli_connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$result_project_material` is probably empty or your query is failing.

Try to do step by step and find where is the error, check if the result is empty before calling `fetch_array()`.

```
$connect = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($connect->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error());
   exit();
}

$result_project_material = $connect->query($sql_project_material);

if($total_project_material = $result_project_material->num_rows > 0) {
   while($result_array = $result_project_material->fetch_array()) {
       $rows_project_material[] = result_array;
   }
}else{
   $rows_project_material = array();
   echo "Empty Result";
}
```